# Difference between A and Some?

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's the sentence from 'How I met your mother'

> I'd feel a little stepford If I turnded down a huge opportunity to chase **(a / some )** guy I'd only known **(for)** two months.

1. what's the difference between **A and Some**?
2. I feel I have to use For here, what's with **For** being omitted?

Comment: It does make sense omitting *for* if the user places stress on either *known* or *two months*.

Comment: You are asking two different questions. The second one was asked sixteen hours prior to your post: ["I've been doing this (for) a week" -- When do you leave out the 'for' when talking about duration, and when do you not?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78569/ive-been-doing-this-for-a-week-when-do-you-leave-out-the-for-when-talk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little difference between *a* and *some* when used in *a/some guy...*.

*A* is the indefinite article, so you are giving an indefinite reference. *A guy* here means *any one guy*. You are not saying anything definite about him, such as providing his identity. Thus, you do not expect your listeners to know who he is.

*Some* before a singular count noun such as *guy* means that the guy's identity is unknown or unimportant. Or you do not care to identify who the guy is. So *a guy* and *some guy* are extremely close in meaning. There are just certain contexts where a native speaker might choose *some* instead of *a*, which is used in many more contexts.

One way in which *some* differs in usage is that *some guy* can (but does not have to) be used in a [flippant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/flippant) or [disparaging](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/disparaging) way. In other words, if you want to refer to an individual in a way that shows that you have a low opinion of him, you can use *some*. But you would also have to use a flippant or disparaging tone. A neutral tone would carry a neutral stance toward the person, just as the indefinite article *a* would.