# He has been buried 4 days or for 4 days?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I have read this sentence and I'm not sure that it's correct
He has been buried 4 days
I think it should have been He has been buried for 4 days. Am I correct?

Comment: Either sentence is fine. The phrase "for four" is sort of an awkward word pattern. You could also say "He was buried four days ago."

Comment: I agree, Sara: there should really be a 'for' in there. People do sometimes leave out prepositions, though...

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78569/ive-been-doing-this-for-a-week-when-do-you-leave-out-the-for-when-talk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are idiomatic:

> He has been buried four days.
>
> He has been buried for four days.

With time phrases, "for" is optional.

> The street has been closed four weeks.
>
> The street has been closed for four weeks.
>
> The egg has been boiling three minutes.
>
> The egg has been boiling for three minutes.