# Correct usage of preposition ***for***

Tags: prepositions

If I say "I was away **ten days** and it rained each day".  
Does it make any difference if i say "I was away **for ten days** and it rained each day".  
 What do I think about it is -  
 There are two clauses

1. I was away
2. ten days

    In the first case both the clauses disjoint but in the second one they are joined by preposition **for**.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.

In time constructions, the preposition **for** indicates duration (and therefore does not indicate a case like accusative or dative) and can be explicitly stated, or implicit.

So, `I was gone ten days` and `I was gone for ten days` are both correct. However, in other types of constructions, especially indicating purpose or direction, you cannot omit **for** since it would have an accustive or dative case.

Comment: Here is another answer that also helps explain this:

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93769/missing-preposition-for-before-time?rq=1

Comment: I would also say that "I was away for ten days" would be more commonly used than "I was away ten days".