# Can the word 'for' can be left out of the following sentence?

Tags: difference, prepositional-phrases

> She has lived in this city for her whole life.

For the above sentence, can I write,

> She has lived in this city her whole life.

If yes, is there any difference between them?

Comment: Are you asking about a particular dialect? This strikes me as an Americanism, but yes you can (in  the US at least) use either one. Both mean the same.

Comment: thank you for your reply and do you know in what case that I have to apply  the word 'for' before the phrase refers to the time.

Comment: I think P.e. Dant's answer is the closest thing you'll find to an actual rule. It's informal, so you probably won't find it in a grammar book.

Answer (score 2):

Phrases which describe a duration of time, or end with *less than*, *more than*, or *fewer than* often omit the preposition **for**. This is a very common idiomatic usage in everyday speech, and not governed specifically by a rule of grammar.

For example:

> She was only here (for) a week.
>   Don't watch television (for) more than two hours.
>   I've been waiting (for) less than a day.
>   I was only gone (for) an hour.
>   I slept there (for) fewer than three nights.

In your example, both versions have the same meaning. In formal writing and for clarity, it is probably best to include the "for."

---

Note: this question has a rich history here. This [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78569/ive-been-doing-this-for-a-week-when-do-you-leave-out-the-for-when-talk) may yield further insights. A question at ELU, found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/193355), provides even more food for thought.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I have one more question. As in this sentence ' I haven't heard from him for three years', can I leave out the word 'for'.

Comment: @HenryWang No, in _I haven't heard from him for three years_, you must include the **for** because without it, the meaning of the sentence is not clear. There may be a better reason, and I'll look for it now,,,

Comment: Hi Sir, did you find a better reason for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this particular case, you can leave out "for". There's really no difference between the two.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I also want to know when the word 'for' is a must in this type of situation?

Comment: Perhaps someone else better understands the exact English rules for this, but I believe this is really just an idiomatic usage of English. For example, read this page for related expressions and explanations:
http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/present_perfect_tense02.html